# How do you calculate the 2D Plane on which an array of Vector3 points are sitting on?

Tags: unity-game-engine, projection, virtual-reality, vertices

Assume you have a large array of Vector3 points. These points were plotted by hand by the player when asked to draw a 2d shape (i.e. a 2d triangle) in a 3-dimentional environment (drawing 2d shapes with htc vive controller in a virtual environment).

I would like to project these points on to a plane to 'flatten' the shape they drew. To do this properly I need to know the average plane they're sitting on so that there is minimal 'squishing/distorting' when projecting them on to it.

Basically, I want to ask them to draw any 2D Shape in the air (which won't be 2D because humans) rotated any way they want and convert that shape into a 2d picture with a known plane for further manipulation.

If you would like to know more specifics I would be happy to provide them.